# Use comma-delimeted values of a column in a query

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have a column in a table that has comma-delimited values (course IDs) that I am trying to use in the query below.... `IN (students.courseids)`

It does not work :-)

If I replace the column value with `IN(1,3,9)` it works fine.

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
SELECT DISTINCT students.Student_Name, students.grade_ID, books.book_title, books.price
FROM (books INNER JOIN courses ON books.course_ID = courses.course_ID) 
      INNER JOIN students ON courses.grade_ID = students.grade_ID
WHERE (students.ID)=3 AND CStr(books.course_ID) IN(students.courseids);
```

Comment: See if this helps :

[Comma Delimited Values - IN clause](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/584680/Using-comma-separated-value-parameter-strings-in-S)

Comment: Could you show the definitions of tables `students`, `courses` and `books`?

Comment: Thanks for your response! See my solution below.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that the IN clause is useless in this instance.  The value you are pulling is a single value, so as far as the engine is concerned, you are looking for only one item on the right, regardless of how many commas are in the string:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        students.Student_Name ,
        students.grade_ID ,
        books.book_title ,
        books.price
FROM    ( books
          INNER JOIN courses ON books.course_ID = courses.course_ID
        )
        INNER JOIN students ON courses.grade_ID = students.grade_ID
WHERE   ( students.ID ) = 3
        AND CStr(books.course_ID) IN ( '9,1,2' );
```

When what you are trying to say, but can't in this way,

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        students.Student_Name ,
        students.grade_ID ,
        books.book_title ,
        books.price
FROM    ( books
          INNER JOIN courses ON books.course_ID = courses.course_ID
        )
        INNER JOIN students ON courses.grade_ID = students.grade_ID
WHERE   ( students.ID ) = 3
        AND CStr(books.course_ID) IN ( '9','1', '2' );
```

There are two solutions I can think of.

The first and better approach is to not use a comma delimited field, but to create a linking table (AKA many to many relationship) between the student table and the courses table.  The linking table contains the keys of the students and the courses that student has access to.  You then join the students, to the linking table, and then the linking table to the courses.

The second, and not so good (also dangerous) possibility is to create a variable that contains the sql statement and then executes it.  This can be very, VERY problematic if anyone can put any kind of data in that string column, and I recommend NOT doing that.

Design your database properly, with appropriately normalized data.

Comment: You are right! I created a linking table and all is well :-) Thanks for all the input!

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    students.Student_Name, students.grade_ID, 
    books.book_title, books.price 
FROM 
    (books 
INNER JOIN 
     courses ON books.course_ID = courses.course_ID) 
INNER JOIN 
    students ON courses.grade_ID = students.grade_ID 
WHERE 
    (students.ID) = 3 
    AND InStr(CStr(books.course_ID), students.courseids) > 0
```